# How can i remove the error on my database?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an assignment on our school but when i click GO it keeps on stating an error like this one:

> 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'term_info_tbl.

This my code:

```
SELECT stud_personal_info.lname,
       subject_tbl.subject_code,
       term_info_tbl.SY
FROM stud_personal_info,
     subject_tbl,
     term_info_tbl,
     stud_subject_tbl
INNER JOIN stud_personal_info ON stud_subject_tbl.stud_id = subject_tbl.sc_id
INNER JOIN term_info_tbl ON stud_subject_tbl.term_id = term_info_tbl
WHERE 1;
```

Comment: `stud_personal_info.lname=Camso`, what is the `=` doing in that line

Comment: Either use JOIN or do it the old way, but not both in the same query

Comment: Now you have `term_info_tbl` and `stud_personal_info` mentioned TWICE in the list of tables

Comment: In fact only use joins. I'm surprised old style joins are apparently still being taught.

Comment: And where did the `stud_subject_tbl` come from, just threw it in for good luck I suppose

Comment: Lets be honest, _its just a mess_ start again. First sit down and think what you are trying to achieve, then try and code it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the column name in your join.

INNER JOIN term_info_tbl ON stud_subject_tbl.term_id = term_info_tbl.[MISSING COLUMN]